# How to create a new column using existing column in SQL Redshift

Tags: sql, syntax, logic, amazon-redshift, dbvisualizer

I am trying to create a new column in SQL with certain conditions in DBVisualizer by connecting redshift data source.
I used the following command to achieve the results but getting syntax error.
I would be really grateful for any help.

**Code:**

```
select existing_col, if(existing_col like '%LM%','LM',if(referrer like
'%LH%','LH',if(existing_col like '%HT%','HT',if(existing_col like '%M_App%','LM','Other 
Business Lines')))) 
AS derived_variable from
db.table_name;
```

**Error:**

```
[Code: 0, SQL State: 42883]  ERROR: function if(boolean, "unknown", "unknown") does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

select existing_col, 
if(existing_col like '%LM%','LM',if(existing_col like '%LH%','LH',if(existing_col like '%HT%','HT',if(existing_col like '%Mint_App%','LM','Other Business Lines')))) 
AS derived_variable from
db.table_name
```

**Expected Output:**

```
existing_col     derived_variable
PB                   Other
OTT                  Other
Mint_App             LM
LSLM                 LM
LMG                  LM
HTTC                 HT
KLH                  LH
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you specify a bit more on the issue? Provide the syntax error, a sample of the data and the desired output of the query would help.

Comment: done, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the error message, the `IF()` function does not exist in Redshift. Therefore, you should use [CASE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CASE_function.html):

```sql
select 
  existing_col, 
  case
    when existing_col like '%LM%' or existing_col like '%Mint_App%' then 'LM'
    when existing_col like '%LH%' then 'LH'
    when existing_col like '%HT%' then 'HT'
    else 'Other'
  end as derived_variable
from db.table_name
```